# How to use Python and Azure Logic App together?

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I run my Python code every week to download multiple attachments from multiple new emails. Those attachments are csv files. I grab some data from them and update a target excel workbook with the retrieved data.

How do I automate this process with Azure Logic Apps so I don't have to manually run Python code every week? I have basic understanding of Azure logic apps but I'm stuck where I want to utilize python to process the data in email attachments in the workflow.

Comment: you could create a python function app and trigger it from logic app ? maybe only a function app could do the trick using a timetrigger

Comment: if you could add some more details it will help to figure out the best options.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Thomas you can trigger the workflow through the logic app's recurrence trigger where you can set the trigger to run once a week and send the email through azure function's HTTP Trigger in python. Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]